# How to switch between accounts created using AWS Organizations from aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

I am using AWS Organizations from my master account to create sub-accounts like prod, dev, playground etc.

Inside the AWS Console it is easy to switch between the accounts by clicking the "Switch Role" button.

How do I achieve the same from the aws-cli using profiles? Can somebody list the least amount of steps necessary to achieve that?

When I search the internet (and I have) I find very different solutions and many of them involving creating new roles from scratch. However, I figure that I should be able to use the AWSServiceRoleForOrganizations role already created by AWS Organizations.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. In the credentials file add:

[master]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[sub-account]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole
source_profile = master

Where XXXXXXXXXXXX is the account number of the sub-account.

Comment: This is outstanding. It means one can create a managed account for an organization and never have to create individual accounts in the managed accounts for CLI work. FYI the official documentation for this is at [Using an IAM role in the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html). Thank you so much for posting this. I'm going to assign a bounty to this answer because it really help point me in the right direction. (P.S. Don't forget to mark this answer as correct so viewers can find it quickly in the future.)

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials` file you need to add different profiles and credentials .

Place your keys in your `~/.aws/credentials` file.

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX

[dev]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX

[playground]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX

[prod]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX
```

Modify your `~/.aws/config` file. Remember to Add the prefix 'profile'

```bash
[default]
region=us-west-2

[profile dev]
region=us-east-1

[profile playground]
region=us-east-1

[profile prod]
region=us-east-1
```

Now you can switch between profile by using the `--profile` flag

```bash
aws s3 ls --profile dev # will use keys and config from dev profile

aws s3 ls # will use keys and config from default profile

aws s3 ls --profile production # will use and config keys from prod profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set env var `AWS_PROFILE` to the respective profile to switch to another profile

```bash
export AWS_PROFILE=profile1
```

**Note:** Assuming you've configured different profiles in your system already

If you didn't configure profiles yet in your local system, you can run the below command:

```bash
aws configure --profile
```